# SQL Reporting Services - COPY reports to another folder

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

This is stupid that I can't figure out how to do this.  I'm in the SQL Reporting Services Report Manager website.  I have some reports in a folder.  I want to copy those reports to a different folder so that I can point those reports to a different datasource.  I still need the original reports in their original folder, pointing to their original datasource.

It's very easy to select reports via checkbox and use the Move functionality, but there doesn't appear to be a way to copy?

Any ideas.

Answer (score 9):

There is no easy way to copy reports in report manager.

I wrote a tool to help me copy reports between servers, you can use the same to copy on the same server too.

http://code.google.com/p/reportsync/

Comment: This answer deserves to be marked as the accepted answer. I will vouch for the ReportSync utility. It is a necessary part of my toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but here is how I copy a report to another folder: 
I open the original report in Report Builder and use 'save as'.

Comment: I think the aim of this question is to save _all_ the reports, so as to avoid having to save them one-by-one if there are hundreds or thousands of reports.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little late, but just in case someone else stumbles upon this thread. I find the easiest way is to click the drop down arrow to the right of the report you would like to copy. Select "Edit in Report Builder". Once that's open just "Save As". Works like a charm.

Comment: Better late than never! :) Thanks so much for this Clint!

Answer (score 2):

Only way I know is manually, one by one. This is in SQL2005.

Navigate to the location of the report(s)
Show details
Click the Edit icon next to the report
On the General tab under the "Report Definition" section, click "Edit"
This prompts a Save File dialogue box. Save the .rdl file somewhere.
Repeat ad nauseum...
Now you can import those reports you've just saved to your new location.

After I wrote this I saw this was the same answer as jimconstable above! Damn!

Answer (score 1):

Within the Browser, if you open the folder then use the drop down there is a Download option.

I compared the file sizes between download and save-as and found them different, so I prefer the download option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these is a simple way to do this. You could pull them all out by going to each report->properties tab->edit. This will let you download the report. Then you can upload it again to another folder. But that sounds like a PITA.

You would be probably be best off the upload from the BIDS to a different folder.