# Error running SSRS powershell cmd

Tags: powershell, web-services, ssrs-2012

I'm running the Powershell commands below from my desktop to deploy the SSRS reports to the on a dev report server.  I get the error below:

Commands:

```
Write-RsFolderContent -ReportServerUri http://serverName/ReportServer -Path "C:\temp\sql\RDL\ProjectName\bin\Debug\” -Destination /ReportTest -Verbose"

New-Rsfolder -ReportServerUri http://serverName/ReportServer -Path "C:\temp\sql\RDL\ProjectName\bin\Debug\” -Name /ReportTest -Verbose
```

Error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-Rsfolder -ReportServerUri http://serverName/ReportServer -Path "C:\temp\sql\RDL\ProjectName\bin\Debug\” -Name /ReportTest -Verbose
VERBOSE: Establishing proxy connection to http://serverName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx...
Failed to establish proxy connection to http://serverName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx : There was an error downloading 'http://serverName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx'.
At C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ReportingServicesTools\0.0.4.7\Functions\Utilities\New-RsWebServiceProxy.ps1:114 char:9
+         throw (New-Object System.Exception("Failed to establish proxy ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to establish proxy connection to http://serverName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx : There was an error downloading 'http://serverName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx'.
```

However, there is no issue navigating to the web service (http://serverName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx.) in IE/Chrome.

Do I have to specify the credentials (username and password) to connect to the web service?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer but I hope it helps someone else. When connecting to a remote server you need to specify the Credentials for authentication purposes like so:

**Note: This example shows how to add a folder but the -Credential param can be added to other commands**

`New-RsFolder -ReportServerUri [Your Web Service URL] -Path / -Name TestFolder -Verbose -Credential 'remoteUserName'`

When you run the command a popup should appear asking for the password. Assuming your credentials are correct, the command should execute successfully.

If -Credential is not specified it will use current user's credentials (Which I am guessing would only work for windows authentication) and consequently fail to establish the remote server proxy connection.

Comment: Found this because I had this use case and this answer saved my hide. Thank you!