# Export SSRS Report from Microsoft 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to export SSRS Reports, [found this](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/09/ssrs-snack-download-all-ssrs-reports.html) , however when using it on 2008 R2 Server, get the following error:

> The path of the item 'WSDL' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply.If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with a slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)

I think this originates in changes made to the WSDL after 2008 R2.

Are there any tools that can be used to export reports located on 2008 R2?
(I can´t open the reports in report viewer and save them)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has a similar issue, when viewing a reports properties, there is an option to edit it. This will start a download. I did not find any other options, this is tideous, however it downloads them at least

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to download all reports with the ReportingServicesTools            cmdlet.

Check out this post: [Download all SSRS reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783093/download-all-ssrs-reports)

Comment: Link only answers are not suitable for this site.

Comment: I have seen & already tries this tool, however it is to working.
No errors or anything, just nothing gets downloaded

Comment: @Murf show the script that you are using to download the SSRS reports

Comment: @tutu There is a link in the question, i use the code 1:1 - for server running more recent versions, the script works fine

Comment: @Murf what have you tried? I am able to find multiple resources on Google, for example: https://stopdebugging.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/error-the-path-of-the-item-is-not-valid-the-full-path-must-be-less-than-260-characters-long-other-restrictions-apply-if-the-report-server-is-in-native-mode-the-path-must-start-with-slash-r/comment-page-1/

Comment: i tried basically everything i found on google. 
the tool you recommended i already used before asking this question,
the script from the question, the solution from your comment, nothing works because of the WSDL changes made after 2008 R2... 
I even tried to download the file as WSDL 1.1 and convert it to 2.0 however this did not work out because the download was not possible ._.
This is really bugging me :(